# Count by first column, count distinct by second column and group output by first column?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I need a Unix command that will read a CSV file (over 700M rows) with the sample below:

```
A, 10
B, 11
C, 12
A, 10
B, 12
D, 10
A, 12
C, 12
```

The command will count the number of occurrence in the first column then count the number of distinct occurrence in column 2 and group the output by entries in column one. Such that the output will look be like below:

```
A, 3, 2
B, 2, 2
C, 2, 1
D, 1, 1
```

Comment: looks like a `tsort` feed

Answer (score 3):

To get the first two columns of the output:

```
$ cut -d, -f1 <file | sort | uniq -c | awk -vOFS=, '{ print $2, $1 }'
A,3
B,2
C,2
D,1
```

This extracts the first column of the original file, sorts it and counts the number of duplicated entries.  The `awk` at the end just swaps the columns and inserts a comma in-between them.

The final column may be had with

```
$ sort -u <file | cut -d, -f1 | uniq -c | awk -vOFS=, '{ print $1 }'
2
2
1
1
```

This sorts the original data and discards the duplicates.  Then the first column is extracted and the number of duplicates of *that* is counted.  The `awk` at the end extracts the counts only.

Combining these using `bash` and `paste`:

```
$ paste -d, <( cut -d, -f1 <file | sort    | uniq -c | awk -vOFS=, '{ print $2, $1 }' ) \
            <( sort -u <file | cut -d, -f1 | uniq -c | awk -vOFS=, '{ print $1 }' )
A,3,2
B,2,2
C,2,1
D,1,1
```

If you pre-sort the data, this may be shortened slightly (and sped up considerably):

```
$ sort -o file file

$ paste -d, <( cut -d, -f1 <file        | uniq -c | awk -vOFS=, '{ print $2, $1 }' ) \
            <( uniq <file | cut -d, -f1 | uniq -c | awk -vOFS=, '{ print $1 }' )
A,3,2
B,2,2
C,2,1
D,1,1
```

Comment: IMHO, this answer should be at the top of the list. No extraneous tools, understandable commands - it's a beauty.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to see if this could be solved using a Perl one-liner, which I was able to figure out:

```
$ perl -F, -ane '$lcnt{$F[0]}++; $ccnt{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++; \
    END { print "$_, $lcnt{$_}, " . (keys %{ $ccnt{$_} }) . "\n" for sort keys %lcnt }' \
      file
A, 3, 2
B, 2, 2
C, 2, 1
D, 1, 1
```

### Breakdown

#### looping over a file

This one-liner might seem uber complicated but it's actually pretty straight forward once you break it down. At the heart of it is this mechanism in Perl:

```
$ perl -F, -ane '...; END { ... }' file
```

This tells Perl to take the file `file` in and loop over it and auto-split it using `-F,` as the separator character, when complete, run the `END {..}` block once and exit.

For example:

```
$ perl -F, -ane 'print "arg1: $F[0] arg2: $F[1]"; END { print "DONE\n" }' file
arg1: A arg2:  10
arg1: B arg2:  11
arg1: C arg2:  12
arg1: A arg2:  10
arg1: B arg2:  12
arg1: D arg2:  10
arg1: A arg2:  12
arg1: C arg2:  12
DONE
```

**NOTE:** Perl's auto-split feature automatically puts the columns into an array `@F`, here I'm using elements 1 & 2, `$F[0]` & `$F[1]`.

#### Counting things

The next thing we need to do is count various bits of the input. For this we'll enlist the power of hashes in Perl. We're going to use 2, `%lcnt` and `%ccnt`.

**NOTE:** One of the more annoying things with Perl is the switching of notation when defining a hash vs. accessing it. When we access it we switch from `%lcnt` to `$lcnt["A"]`, but I digress.

```
$lcnt{$F[0]}++; $ccnt{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++;
```

- `%lcnt` - count of characters from the 1st column
- `%ccnt` - 2 dimensional hash containing 2 coordinates to access a count of 2nd column

**NOTE:** Counting things in this manner allows for the unique function to be performed simply by how we're counting the bits.

For example, let's examine the contents of the `%lcnt` hash:

```
$ perl -F, -ane '$lcnt{$F[0]}++; $ccnt{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++; \
    END { print "key: $_\n" for sort keys %lcnt }' file
key: A
key: B
key: C
key: D
```

If we want to see the value for each hash:

```
$ perl -F, -ane '$lcnt{$F[0]}++; $ccnt{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++; \
    END { print "key: $_ val: $lcnt{$_}\n" for sort keys %lcnt }' file
key: A val: 3
key: B val: 2
key: C val: 2
key: D val: 1
```

**NOTE:** Here we can see that the `$lcnt{$F[0]}++` has done all the hard work of *counting* each character as we've looped through the file and added them to the hash `%lcnt`.

#### This is the END

The last piece of the puzzle is to display all this collected information in a useful way. For that we'll use this in the `END {...}`:

```
print "$_, $lcnt{$_}, " . (keys %{ $ccnt{$_} }) . "\n" for sort keys %lcnt
```

This loops through the list of keys from `%lcnt` and prints the following line:

```
$_, $lcnt{$_}, " . (keys %{ $ccnt{$_} }) . "\n"
```

If it's hard to see the above's structure, here it is more generally:

```
A, 3, 2
      ^--- (keys %{ $ccnt{$_} })  ## count of unique columns for each character ($_)
   ^------ $lcnt{$_}              ## count of each character
^--------- $_                     ## character
```

This will produce a line that contains the character (`$_`), the count value for  this character (`$lcnt{$_}`) and then the count of unique values from the 2nd column for each character.

#### References

- [How can I find the number of keys in a hash in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109095/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-keys-in-a-hash-in-perl)
- [How do I concatenate a string?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=32418)
- [The top 10 tricks of Perl one-liners](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/the-top-10-tricks-of-perl-one-liners-v2)
- [Perl One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-one/)
- [9.4. Hashes of Hashes](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch09_04.htm)
- [Multi dimensional hashes in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-hashes)
- [How can I get the unique keys from two hashes?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20can%20I%20get%20the%20unique%20keys%20from%20two%20hashes%3F)
- [slmingol/README.md](https://gist.github.com/slmingol/ed07abb574b08416beb650a9ecea60a0)

Answer (score 2):

With a small `sqlite3` script running from command line, where `input.csv` is your input data:

```sql
sqlite3 -batch <<EOF
.mode csv

CREATE TABLE data (letter TEXT, number INTEGER);

.import input.csv data

SELECT letter, COUNT(*) AS lcount, COUNT(DISTINCT number) AS dcount
FROM data
GROUP BY letter ;
EOF
```

This works as so

```
$ bash query.sqlite 
A,3,2
B,2,2
C,2,1
D,1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datamash -t, -s -g 1 count 1 countunique 2 < input.txt
```

**Input**

```
A, 10
B, 11
C, 12
A, 10
B, 12
D, 10
A, 12
C, 12
```

**Output**

```
A,3,2
B,2,2
C,2,1
D,1,1
```